# Getting value of a boolean control in v4l2

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, v4l2

I am trying to adjust the brightness of a camera. Before setting brightness, I am trying to check whether brightness is in auto mode or not. We can do so by checking **volatile** flag but I am running kernel version 2.6.32 which does not have this functionality. So, the other option is to check **V4L2_CID_AUTOBRIGHTNESS**, which I am doing but it is returning EINVAL.

I am using following code to get the value:

```
struct v4l2_control control;

control.id = V4L2_CID_BRIGHTNESS;       // This is working fine
//control.id = V4L2_CID_AUTOBRIGHTNESS; // This is giving EINVAL in ioctl


if (-1 == ioctl(camDesc, VIDIOC_G_CTRL, &control))
   cerr << "VIDIOC_G_CTRL" << "   ::  " << errno << endl ;
else
   cout << "Successfully got property. Value :: " << control.value << endl;
```

May be **V4L2_CID_AUTOBRIGHTNESS** is a boolean property that's why it is giving **EINVAL**, but then I am not able to find any other method by which I can get the value of boolean property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the properties (user controls) can be disabled, so if we will directly change there value using **v4l2_control**, then it may give some error.

Best way to do is, by checking the appropriate flags using **queryctrl** and then set the actual value.

```
struct v4l2_queryctrl queryctrl;
queryctrl.id = V4L2_CID_BRIGHTNESS;  // V4L2_CID_AUTOBRIGHTNESS i.e. any user ctrl

if (-1 == ioctl(camDesc, VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL, &queryctrl))
{
   if (errno != EINVAL)
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   else
   {
      cerr << "ERROR :: Unable to set property (NOT SUPPORTED)\n";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
else if (queryctrl.flags & V4L2_CTRL_FLAG_DISABLED)
{
   cout << "ERROR :: Unable to set property (DISABLED).\n";
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else
{
  struct v4l2_control control;
  control.id = queryctrl.id;
  control.value = eValue;      // Any value

  if (-1 == ioctl(camDesc, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control))
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  cout << "Successfully set property." << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the V4L2 the set of IOCTL is mostly implemented (or not implemented) on side of the actual sensor. This one is not an exception. Thus, you have two potential problems here: a) a driver of the actual sensor does not implement the specific IOCTL, b) the IOCTL is only to set a property, though I think you still may read last set value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You mentioned in point (b), **the IOCTL is only to set a property**, but you can use IOCTL to get a property as well. It is governed by the value of **request**. As in my case, If you will pass **VIDIOC_G_CTRL** then you will get the property and in case of **VIDIOC_S_CTRL** you will get the property.

Comment: Yes, because usually property is cached in the internal structures (which might be not a case with some drivers).